# Disabling Interactive Touchscreen Features in RichTextBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am developing a Windows 10 UWP app where I want text to be only highlighted upon touch without the display of the interactive *Copy to clipboard* and *Two finger swipe* features that can be seen in the screen shot below...

[image]

I don't want those three circles.

Although my code is probably not relevant, I'm including it.

Here is my XAML...

```
<RichTextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                       x:Name="myRichTextBlock"                                              
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       TextIndent="30"
                       TextAlignment="Left"
                       Foreground="Green"
                       FontSize="36"
                       FontFamily="Cambria"
                       Margin="15"                       
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       SelectionHighlightColor="Orange"                       
                       IsTextSelectionEnabled="True"
                       SelectionChanged="myRichTextBlock_SelectionChanged"/>
```

And here what I have in the SelectionChanged function...

```
private void myRichTextBlock_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
            if (_isFirstSelection)
            {
                _isFirstSelection = false;
                _textPointer1 = myRichTextBlock.SelectionStart;                
            }
            TextPointer textPointer2 = myRichTextBlock.SelectionEnd;
            if (textPointer2.Offset > _textPointer1.Offset)
            {                                
                myRichTextBlock.Select(_textPointer1, textPointer2);
            }
        }
```

Where _textPointer1 is a TextPointer object defined in the constructor.

Is it possible to get rid of the interactive elements in XAML through a property I am not aware of?

Comment: If you want to get rid of the interactive elements in XAML through a property    , you should be able to set the `IsTextSelectionEnabled` to false.

Comment: That disables ALL text selection. I don't want text selection disabled, just the interactive features.